# Registration process for tourists in South East Asian countries

Tags: indian-citizens, thailand, vietnam, southeast-asia, cambodia

I am traveling to Vietnam, Cambodia and Thailand. I am struggling to find proper information about the requirement of registration. I know hotels register you automatically but I plan to stay at Homestays advertised on Booking.com, and I am not sure if these count as hotels, and if they will register me. In addition, I plan to stay in a Thai kickboxing camp in Thailand too.

In a rare scenario if they refuse, what are my possible options if the law demands that I should be registered?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, in all three countries, any registration paperwork is the **host's responsibility, not the visitor's**.  So while you can always ask about registration if you want to, it's the host, not you, who could (theoretically) end up on hot water if they don't.

Note that in Thailand, long-term residents *do* have to register every 90 days or risk fines, but this doesn't apply to tourist visas.  More detail on how the TM30 system works: https://www.thethailandlife.com/tm30-guide